# Django django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column

Tags: django

Есть модель:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    parent_place = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = PlainLocationField(based_fields=['city'], zoom=7)
```

При попытке править, выдаёт ошибку:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column:
>   admin_place.parent_place_id

Пытаюсь использовать расширение [django-location-field](https://github.com/caioariede/django-location-field).

Пример [тут](https://github.com/caioariede/django-location-field/blob/master/example/dlf_app/models.py)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добавить в вашу существующую базу данных необходимую таблицу(у меня это была account_profile), необходимо для начала скачать «DB Browser for SQLite» и проделать следующее:

Скопируйте уже имеющуюся ‘db.sqlite3’ в какую-нибудь папку.
Удалите ее из папки с проектом.
Запустите «python3 manage.py make migrations», затем «python3 manage.py migrate».
Откройте вашу новую базу данных в «DB Browser for SQLite».
Затем вам необходимо экспортировать ‘account_profile’-таблицу как CSV файл.   Показано в image1(снизу комментария)
Затем удалите вашу новую ДБ и закиньте обратно старую
Откройте теперь вашу старую ДБ в «DB Browser for SQLite», нажмите «Файл»—>«Импорт»—>«Таблицу как файл CSV» и выберите ваш CSV файл(как раз в нем и содержится необходимая таблица)
Затем вы увидите, что в таблице столбцы называются как ‘field1’ и ‘field2’, переменяйте их в ‘id’ ’user_id’ соответственно. Показано на image2 и image3
Затем можно либо удалить в базе данных админа, либо посмотреть, какой у него id и вписать(например у админа id-5, пишем в столбец ‘id’ - ‘1’, в столбец ‘user_id’ - ‘5’)

[image: image1]

---

[image: image2]

---

[image]

---

[image: Результат]

Comment: Связанный вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61095891/13209546

Answer (score 0):

Ваша модель и таблица в БД не синхронизированы друг с другом.

Для того, чтобы makemigration & migrate выполнились корректно Вам необходимо открыть вашу DB и вручную добавить туда поле "parent_place_id" (только поле и его тип, Foreign Key прописывать не нужно).
После этого makemigration & migrate выполняться без ошибок.

Почему сам makemigration не может добавить это поле в таблицу, я пока не понял. Видимо есть недоработки функционала модификации таблиц.